# Can this parsing script be made any faster ? are they bottlenecks?

Tags: perl

I have a set of files about 10.000 files in a directory. The total size of all the files is about 1GB. Parsing(Inluding Insert to Mysql) 1 of the files, takes about 2 minutes. If it progresses like this, it could take me 13 full days to parse these files. There is certainly something wrong because it's not normal. I have 8GB ram, my specs are quite ok.

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI; # Load the DBI module for connection to mysql database (or others)
use Time::localtime; # Load Time::localtime module used to convert dates and times
use Net::IP;
my @datasetarray;
my $Dir = "/root/updates\/processed";

opendir my($dh), $Dir or die "Could not open directory [$Dir]: $!";

foreach my $file ( sort { $a cmp $b } readdir $dh )
    {
    next if $file eq "." or $file eq "..";

    print "$file\n";
    unless ($file=~/\.hr$/){next;}


    my $file = $Dir."/".$file;  

    open (IN, $file) or die "error reading file: ", $file,"\n";


    my $record_id = "";
        my $time="";
    my $type = "";
    my $peer_ip = "";
    my $peer_as = "";
    my $local_ip = "";
    my $local_as = "";
    my $next_hop = "";
    my @nodes_and_index = ();
    my @withdraw_prefix = ();
    my @announce_prefix = ();
    my $tmphash = {};

    while (<IN>) {          
        no warnings 'uninitialized';

        if (/^TIME/) {

            if ($type) {$tmphash->{'type'} = $type;}
            if ($peer_ip) {$tmphash->{'peer_ip'} = $peer_ip;}
            if ($peer_as) {$tmphash->{'peer_as'} = $peer_as;}
            if ($local_ip) {$tmphash->{'local_ip'} = $local_ip;}
            if ($local_as) {$tmphash->{'local_as'} = $local_as;}
            if ($next_hop) {$tmphash->{'next_hop'} = $next_hop;}
            if (@nodes_and_index) {push @{$tmphash->{'nodes_and_index'}}, @nodes_and_index;}  
            if (@withdraw_prefix) {push @{$tmphash->{'withdraw_prefix'}}, @withdraw_prefix;}
            if (@announce_prefix) {push @{$tmphash->{'announce_prefix'}}, @announce_prefix;}


            if ($record_id) {  
                        $tmphash->{'time'} = $record_id;
                        push @datasetarray, $tmphash;
                        $tmphash = {};
                    }        

            $peer_as = "";
            $peer_ip = "";
            $type = "";
            $local_ip = "";
            $local_as = "";
            $next_hop = "";
            $record_id = "";
            $time="";
            @nodes_and_index = ();
            @withdraw_prefix = ();
            @announce_prefix = ();


            my @time = split '\s', $_;
            $record_id = $time[1]." ".$time[2];


        } elsif (/^TYPE/) {
            my @type_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $type = $type_tmp[1];

        } elsif (/^FROM/) {
            my @from_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $peer_ip = $from_tmp[1];
            $peer_as = $from_tmp[2];
            $peer_as =~ s/AS//; 

        } elsif (/^TO/) {
            my @to_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $local_ip = $to_tmp[1];
            $local_as = $to_tmp[2];
            $local_as =~ s/AS//;

        } elsif (/^ASPATH/) {

            my @nodes_tmp = split '\s', $_;
                shift @nodes_tmp;       
            my $index = 0;

            foreach my $node (@nodes_tmp) {
                    $index++;
            push @nodes_and_index, [$node , $index]; 
             }  

        }elsif (/^NEXT_HOP/) {  

            my @next_hop_tmp = split '\s', $_;
            $next_hop = $next_hop_tmp[1];  

        }elsif (/^WITHDRAW/) {
            while (<IN>) {       
                     last if !/^ +/;  
                     push @withdraw_prefix, [$_] ;           

                 }

        }elsif (/^ANNOUNCE/) {

                 while (<IN>) {        
                     last if !/^ +/;
                     push @announce_prefix, [$_];

                 }  

            }


    }
    close IN;


    if ($type) {$tmphash->{'type'} = $type;} 
        if ($peer_ip) {$tmphash->{'peer_ip'} = $peer_ip;}
        if ($peer_as) {$tmphash->{'peer_as'} = $peer_as;} 
        if ($local_ip) {$tmphash->{'local_ip'} = $local_ip;} 
        if ($local_as) {$tmphash->{'local_as'} = $local_as;} 
        if ($next_hop) {$tmphash->{'next_hop'} = $next_hop;} 
        if (@nodes_and_index) {push @{$tmphash->{'nodes_and_index'}}, @nodes_and_index;}  
        if (@withdraw_prefix) {push @{$tmphash->{'withdraw_prefix'}}, @withdraw_prefix;}  
        if (@announce_prefix) {push @{$tmphash->{'announce_prefix'}}, @announce_prefix;}  

        if ($record_id) {  
             $tmphash->{'time'} = $record_id; 
             push @datasetarray, $tmphash;
            $tmphash = {};
        }  

 databaseloader(); #Call database loader subroutine;
 @datasetarray=();


}  




###########################################DATABASE INSERTS########################################################

sub databaseloader {

my $hostname;
my $username;
my $password;
my $database_name;
my $error_log;
if(@ARGV > 0) {
    GetOptions('h|hostname=s' => \$hostname,
           'u|user=s' => \$username,
           'p|password=s' => \$password,
           'db|database_name=s' => \$database_name,
           'e|error_log=s' => \$error_log
           );
}

#defaults
if(! defined $hostname) {
    $hostname = "localhost";
}
if(! defined $username) {
    $username = "root";
}
if(! defined $password) {    
    $password = "admin";
}
if(! defined $database_name) {    
    $database_name = "BGPstorage";
}
if(! defined $error_log) {
    `touch /tmp/error_log`;
    $error_log = "/tmp/error_log";
}

#print "making connection to database named $database_name on $hostname with user: $username and password: $password\n" ;

#connect to mysql database
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:mysql:$database_name:$hostname", $username, $password, {
      PrintError => 1,
      RaiseError => 0
  } ) or die "Can't connect to the database: $DBI::errstr\n";



                 ### Prepare SQL statements ###



### Update details table --> information about the UPDATE message (Update_ID,Time,Type,Peer_IP)
my $Update_detail= $dbh->prepare_cached("INSERT IGNORE INTO update_detail VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)" ) or die "Can't prepare SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";


### Announce updates table --> information about the announce UPDATE message (Announce_UpdateID,Prefix,Update_ID)
my $Announce_update= $dbh->prepare_cached("INSERT IGNORE INTO announce_update VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)" ) or die "Can't prepare SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";


### Withdraw updates table --> information about the withdraw UPDATE message (Withdraw_UpdateID,Prefix,Update_ID)
my $Withdraw_update= $dbh->prepare_cached("INSERT IGNORE INTO withdraw_update VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)" ) or die "Can't prepare SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";

### AS PATH table --> information about the Autonomous system PATHS (AS_Path_ID,Path_Index,AS_No,Update_ID) i.e. (001,1,2321| 002,1,322)
my $as_path = $dbh->prepare_cached("INSERT IGNORE INTO as_path VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)" ) or die "Can't prepare SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";



#Define Variables

my $TIME;
my $TYPE;
my $PEERAS;
my $PEERIP;
my $LOCALAS;
my $LOCALIP;
my $MYNEXTHOP;
my @WITHDRAWALS;
my @ANNOUNCED;
my $UpdateKey; #Get the last updated key value
foreach my $row (@datasetarray) {
    no warnings 'uninitialized';



    my $TIME = $row->{'time'} ;
    my $TYPE = $row->{'type'} ;
    my $PEERAS = $row->{'peer_as'};
    my $PEERIP = $row->{'peer_ip'};
    my $LOCALAS = $row->{'local_as'};
    my $LOCALIP = $row->{'local_ip'};
    my $MYNEXTHOP = $row->{'next_hop'};
    my @ASPATH = @{$row->{'nodes_and_index'}} if ref $row->{'nodes_and_index'} eq 'ARRAY';
    my @WITHDRAWALS = @{$row->{'withdraw_prefix'}} if ref $row->{'withdraw_prefix'} eq 'ARRAY';
    my @ANNOUNCED = @{$row->{'announce_prefix'}} if ref $row->{'announce_prefix'} eq 'ARRAY';



    #INSERT INTO UPDATES TABLE
    my $mysql_dt = sprintf('20%3$s-%1$s-%2$s %4$s', split(/[\/ ]/, $TIME));
    $Update_detail->execute($mysql_dt,$TYPE,$PEERIP);  #Insert into Update_detail table
    $UpdateKey = $Update_detail->{mysql_insertid}; #Get primary key of last inserted statement

    #INSERT INTO AS PATH TABLE
    foreach my $as (@ASPATH) {  
            no warnings 'uninitialized';
            $as_path->execute($as->[1],$as->[0],$UpdateKey);

        } 

    #INSERT INTO ANNOUNCE TABLE
    foreach my $au (@ANNOUNCED) {
            no warnings 'uninitialized';
                        my $val=$au->[0];
            $val=~s/^\s+//;   #To remove leading whitespace in the IP           
            my $prefix = new Net::IP ($val) or die (Net::IP::Error());
            my $IP = $prefix->ip();
            my $subnetmask = $prefix->mask();
            $Announce_update->execute($IP,$subnetmask,$UpdateKey);

        } 

    #INSERT INTO WITHDRAW TABLE
    foreach my $wd (@WITHDRAWALS) {
            no warnings 'uninitialized';
            my $val=$wd->[0];
            $val=~s/^\s+//;   #To remove leading whitespace in the IP
            my $prefix = new Net::IP ($val) or die (Net::IP::Error());
            my $IP = $prefix->ip(); 
            my $subnetmask = $prefix->mask();
            $Withdraw_update->execute($IP,$subnetmask,$UpdateKey);
        } 




}

}
print "\nInsertion Completed\n";
```

**Example of file text structure :**

```
TIME: 07/27/13 09:00:00
TYPE: BGP4MP/MESSAGE/Update
FROM: 10.255.9.4 AS172193
TO: 10.255.9.10 AS676767
WITHDRAW
  10.27.236.0/24

TIME: 07/27/13 09:00:00
TYPE: BGP4MP/MESSAGE/Update
FROM: 10.255.9.4 AS172193
TO: 10.255.9.10 AS676767
ORIGIN: IGP
ASPATH: 172193 19601 14835 4758 15731 410 913 72 2113 7659 5024
NEXT_HOP: 10.255.9.126
ANNOUNCE
  10.27.236.0/24

TIME: 07/27/13 09:00:02
TYPE: BGP4MP/MESSAGE/Update
FROM: 10.255.9.4 AS172193
TO: 10.255.9.10 AS676767
ORIGIN: IGP
ASPATH: 172193 19601 14835 3352 3687 7196 14384 15037 9486 8580
NEXT_HOP: 10.255.9.126
ANNOUNCE
  10.2.86.0/24
  10.2.92.0/24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't reconnect to the database on each loop iteration

a simple way to do this is to add a variable `my $dbh=0` below the "use" declarations at the top of the file and then alter the connect statement in `databaseloader` sub from

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:mysql:$database_name:$hostname", $username, $password, {
      PrintError => 1,
      RaiseError => 0
  } ) or die "Can't connect to the database: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

to something like this

```
if (not($dbh)) {
$dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:mysql:$database_name:$hostname", $username, $password, {
          PrintError => 1,
          RaiseError => 0
      } ) or die "Can't connect to the database: $DBI::errstr\n";
}
```

connecting only once will be a big performance gain.  Probably you want to move all the getOpt stuff and the defaults out of that sub too, but caching the database handle is the win.

Comment: is there any chance that sorting the files prior to parsing as i did could be a major performance bottleneck ? I made the changes as you advised but i really haven't seen much satisfying results.

Comment: you are sorting the files once, any performance problems are more likely to be with repeated operations.  My suggestion of reusing the db handle is an obvious design feature that will help with speed.  The other ideas to speed it up become more like guesswork depending on your data, the exact size of the database and so on.  The suggestion of AKHolland to use a profiler should be your next step

Answer (score 1):

Running a profiling tool such as [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aNYTProf) and looking at the output is the best way to determine this. Adding `-D:NYTProf` to the first line, running the script, and then running `nytprofhtml` will show you where the program is spending the most time. Then if you find that it's spending a lot of time connecting to the database, or running some particular regex, you can narrow down your efforts.

Comment: thanks i heard about the tool but had some issues installing it :( will try again later.